# Using lucene.net trunk on a production application

Tags: lucene.net

Currently I'm prototyping search with Lucene.Net-2.0-004 on a web application. It's working very well, but it's quite an old version of Lucene.net

Is it "safe" to use the trunk version ?
Are you doing it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We're currently using Lucene.Net 2.0.0.4 in our beta release as well. So far, it seems to do what we need, though I've heard that the latest not-yet-officially-released versions of Lucene.Net fix several issues.

You can see a list of the tagged versions of Lucene.Net here:
https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/incubator/lucene.net/tags/

This StackOverflow question has some background about the current incubation status of Lucene.NET:
[Lucene.Net and incubation status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/435207/lucene-net-and-incubation-status)

And in the answer to this StackOverflow question about the [latest version of Lucene.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554608/what-is-the-latest-version-of-lucene-net), one person mentioned using 2.3.1.

I hope the Lucene.Net project releases another "official" version soon, preferably with a list of changes / fixes since 2.0.0.4.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I used it for a project for at least 6 months. I eventually upgraded to 2.1 because I wanted a bit of the functionality they added. I've found it to be stable as well - it's been running 8 months or so w/o a hiccup. Since it's a port of the Java version and tends to run behind that version, I'd expect the .NET versions to be a bit more stable (since the port would hopefully be done off of a more stable version).